Tracking errors per round
I was wondering if there is a way (even if it may be manual than a single function call) to tag bit flips (or phase errors) in qubits in a circuit after each round. For example, suppose I examine the following built-in d=3 circuit:
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 1) 1
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 0) 2
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 1) 3
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 1) 5
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 3) 8
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 2) 9
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 3) 10
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 2) 11
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 3) 12
QUBIT_COORDS(6, 2) 13
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 4) 14
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 5) 15
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 4) 16
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 5) 17
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 4) 18
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 5) 19
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 6) 25
R 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
X_ERROR(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
R 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
TICK
DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
H 2 11 16 25
DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
TICK
CX 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
TICK
CX 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
TICK
CX 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
TICK
CX 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
TICK
H 2 11 16 25
DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
TICK
X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
MR 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
# MARK 1 [1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19]
X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
DETECTOR(0, 4, 0) rec[-4]
DETECTOR(2, 2, 0) rec[-7]
DETECTOR(4, 4, 0) rec[-2]
DETECTOR(6, 2, 0) rec[-5]
REPEAT 2 {
    TICK
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
    H 2 11 16 25
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
    TICK
    CX 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
    TICK
    CX 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
    TICK
    CX 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
    TICK
    CX 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
    TICK
    H 2 11 16 25
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
    TICK
    X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
    MR 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
    # MARKS 2, 3 [1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19]
    X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
    SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
    DETECTOR(2, 0, 0) rec[-8] rec[-16]
    DETECTOR(2, 2, 0) rec[-7] rec[-15]
    DETECTOR(4, 2, 0) rec[-6] rec[-14]
    DETECTOR(6, 2, 0) rec[-5] rec[-13]
    DETECTOR(0, 4, 0) rec[-4] rec[-12]
    DETECTOR(2, 4, 0) rec[-3] rec[-11]
    DETECTOR(4, 4, 0) rec[-2] rec[-10]
    DETECTOR(4, 6, 0) rec[-1] rec[-9]
}
X_ERROR(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
M 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
# MARK FINAL [1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19]
DETECTOR(0, 4, 1) rec[-3] rec[-6] rec[-13]
DETECTOR(2, 2, 1) rec[-5] rec[-6] rec[-8] rec[-9] rec[-16]
DETECTOR(4, 4, 1) rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-4] rec[-5] rec[-11]
DETECTOR(6, 2, 1) rec[-4] rec[-7] rec[-14]
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-7] rec[-8] rec[-9]

At each point marked with 'MARK [round/FINAL] [qubits]', I am thinking about accessing the error state of the (data) qubits.
I understand from other postings that there is an open issue for the general problem of tracking the errors each time they appear, but this use case might be simpler than what is raised in the issue. I also understand that I could use stim.FlipSimulator for the measure qubits, but I am not sure if that would provide the information I need for data qubits.
Do you think you could provide any guidance to obtain the cumulative error states of a set of data qubits like above? Even if the approach is a bit more manual and slower in simulation speed, I would be happy to give it a try.

The flip simulator will also tell you the state of errors on the data qubits.

@CraigGidney Thanks a lot. If I run the get_measurement_flips routine, I can get the state of errors on the measurements, which could include the data qubits (I checked that with the default record_index argument, the dimension of the returned array for each shot is the same as what the circuit sampler object would give for measurements). However, what I was hoping to obtain was the error state at the end of each round, before the measurement of the data qubits (annotated using the comments '# MARK ...' above), because I wanted to use compactified truth info. for NN training purposes.

If you peek at their state at the end of each round you can get this information. You can also add MPP operations to measure the detectors and observables to peek at them. Just don't include them in detectors and the decoder can't see them by default.

That makes sense. Thanks a lot!
